# Sort these variables in order (transform the words into a number equal to its length). (use conditions)

Tags: php

$variable1 = “toto”;

$variable2 = “helmut”;

$variable3 = 2;

*QUESTION:* Sort these variables in order (transform the words into a number equal to its length). (use conditions if-else(or any other conditions))

Here's the code i made, it's bit long and i feel like i used too much, but the thing is -> it works if i use "A", "B", "C" as variables, but it doesn't if i use "variable1", "variable2", "variable3". I cannot change them as my teacher stated. so my code doesn't work.

```
$variable1 = "toto"; // strlen($variable1) = 4

$variable2 = "helmut"; // strlen($variable2) = 6

$variable3 = 2;

if (strlen($variable1) <= strlen($variable2)) {

    if($variable3 <= strlen($variable1) ) {
        echo $variable3 . "<br>" . strlen($variable1) . "<br>" . strlen($variable2);
    }
    if(strlen($variable2) <= $variable3) {
        echo strlen($variable1) . "<br>" . strlen($variable2) . "<br>" . $variable3;
    }
    else {
        echo strlen($variable1) . "<br>" . $variable3 . "<br>" . strlen($variable2);
    }
}

else {

    
if ($variable3 <= strlen($variable2) ) {
        echo $variable3 . "<br>" . strlen($variable2) . "<br>" . strlen($variable1);
    }
    if ($variable3 <= strlen($variable1) {
        echo strlen($variable2) . "<br>" . $variable3 . "<br>" . strlen($variable1);
    }
    else {
       echo strlen($variable2) . "<br>" . strlen($variable1) . "<br>" . $variable3;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a Homework question, please read this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need.

```
$variable1 = 'todo';
$variable2 = 'tetete';
$variable3 = 2;

$variablesToSort = [$variable1, $variable2, $variable3];

usort($variablesToSort, 'sortByLenght');

foreach($variablesToSort as $sortedVariable) {
    echo $sortedVariable . ' ';
}

function sortByLenght($firstWord, $secondWord) {
    return strlen($firstWord) <=> strlen($secondWord);
}
```

Update answer using if else.

```
$variable1 = '1';
$variable2 = '2';
$variable3 = 3;

$isFirstLongerThanSecond = strlen($variable1) > strlen($variable2);
$isSecondLongerThanThird = strlen($variable2) > strlen($variable3);
$isFirstLongerThanThird = strlen($variable1) > strlen($variable3);

if ($isFirstLongerThanSecond) {
    if ($isSecondLongerThanThird) {
            echo "$variable3 $variable2  $variable1";
    } elseif ($isFirstLongerThanThird) {
            echo "$variable2 $variable3  $variable1";
    } else {
        echo "$variable2 $variable1  $variable3";
    }
} else if ($isSecondLongerThanThird) {
    if ($isFirstLongerThanThird) {
        echo "$variable3 $variable1 $variable2";
    } else {
        echo "$variable1 $variable3  $variable2";
    }
} else if ($isFirstLongerThanThird) {
     echo "$variable3 $variable1 $variable2";
} else {
     echo "$variable1 $variable2  $variable3";
}
```

Comment: That's very good code, but i have to answer it using only conditions (if else )

Comment: I updated my answer using if else only. Can you test it?